# push data into dojo objectstore

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am trying to push a new entry to an objectstore using dojo framework.
The hierarchy looks like below:

```
Job Type
   job1
   job2
   job3
   job4
```

Now, I want to insert a new job `job6` and place it at the first using javascript. I am using the before option as per dojo framework. However, I am not able to do so. Below is the code snippet:

```
objectStore.put({
    id: unid,
    name: unid.replace(typ,''),
    type:typ,
    before: "job1",
    project:"jobs",
    parent:typ
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**update:** [`before`](https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/2141e03cc9011870db5e3dedfb043d6cf9a86c97/store/api/Store.js#L141) is listed as a member of `PutDirectives` in the API specification, but it is not actually implemented in the [put() code](https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/master/store/Memory.js#L58) (I checked Memory store and DataStore). New items are simplly appended to the end.

There are two work-arounds:

1. Consider the store a non-ordered collection and use other means of sorting (like the `sortInfo` property of [DataGrids](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html)). This will depend on how you are using the store. This is probably the best option, as the store is not supposed to have any structure other than a bag of id's. The `before` option may just be a remnant from a previous version of Dojo.
2. Use manual array manipulation and `Memory.setData()` to modify the store. This assumes use of a Memory store. (See code below)
3. *Bonus work-around: modify Dojo's store to honor the `before` option*

**Using manual array manipulation and `Memory.setData()` to modify the store:**

```js
require(["dojo/store/Memory"], function(Memory) {
  // Initialize
  var data = [
    {id: "job1", name: "Job 1"},
    {id: "job2", name: "Job 2"},
  ];   
  objectStore = new Memory({data: data});
    
  console.log('BEFORE insert:');
  console.log(objectStore.data);

  // Get data from store as array
  var tmpData = objectStore.data;
    
  // Modify array: insert new item at beginning
  var newObject = {id: "job3", name: "New Job"};
  tmpData.unshift(newObject);
  
  // Set data of objectStore to newly modified array
  objectStore.setData(tmpData);
    
  console.log('AFTER insert:'); 
  console.log(objectStore.data);

});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

Comment: No go buddy. It does not place the job, however when I refresh the page it will arranged asc sort order

Comment: @user2582322: You will have to provide more information in your question. What are you seeing? (how are you visualizing the store?) Which Dojo API are you using, exactly? (dojo.data.ObjectStore, dojo/store... why not dstore?) A [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces your issue would really help.

Comment: @user2582322: I updated my answer with code for a work-around that works.